# how to vlookup if prefix found in the list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

[image]

HI. 
how can i come up with return value of "company name" (column H) at Column B IF any of the "PrefiX" (Column G) found at "con no" (Column A).

Sample of outcome needed as in column B.

Sample:
**6200**11113 = DD
**CN**1234 = BB

thanks

Comment: Please specify what output you are trying to achieve

Comment: Have a look at [ask] a question with a [mcve]. Right now we would have no idea about what you are trying since non of the data in column G seems to be resembled in column A. Be more specific and include your own attempt, it doesnt matter how poor.

Comment: Hi. i already edit my sample and question

Comment: This would be simple if prefixes had a constant length. But with variable length, I doubt there is a solution that does not include VB.

Comment: Create an UDF looping through the A & G Columns .. with VBA function Instr(Cell in A, Cell in B)<>0  to find the match and return the H Col Value

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis No need for VB, just use an Array Formula instead

Answer (score 2):

```
=INDEX($H:$H,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G$1:$G$7)/(--(FIND($G$1:$G$7,$A2)=1)*--(LEN($G$1:$G$7)>0)),1),1)
```

Breaking this down, the `INDEX` retrieves the ***N<sup>th</sup>*** item from Column H (Company name).  To find the value of ***N***, we are using [the `AGGREGATE` function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df)

`AGGREGATE` is a weird function - it lets us use things like `MAX` or `LARGE` or `SUM` while ignoring any error values.  In this case, we will be using it for `SMALL` (first argument, `15`), while Ignoring Error Values (second argument, `6`).  We will want the *very* smallest value, so the fourth argument will be `1`.  (If we wanted the second smallest, it would be `2`, and so on)

```
=INDEX($H:$H,AGGREGATE(15,6, <SOMETHING> ,1),1)
```

So, all we need now is a list of values to compare!  To make things *slightly* simpler, I'll break that bit of the code out for you here:

```
ROW($G$1:$G$7) / (--(FIND($G$1:$G$7,$A2)=1) * --(LEN($G$1:$G$7)>0))
```

There are 3 parts to this.  The first, `ROW($G$1:$G$7)`is the actual value we want to retrieve - these will be the Row Numbers for each Prefix that matches your value.  On its own, however, it will be *all* the row numbers.  Since we are skipping errors, we want any Rows that *don't* match the prefix to throw an error.  The easiest way to do this is to Divide by Zero

At the start of `--(FIND($G$1:$G$7,$A2)=1)` and `--(LEN($G$1:$G$7)>0)` we have a double-negative.  This is a quick way to convert `True` and `False` to `1` and `0`.  Only when both tests are `True` will we *not* divide by `0`, as this table shows:

```
A | B | A*B
1 | 1 |  1
1 | 0 |  0
0 | 1 |  0
0 | 0 |  0
```

Starting with the second test first (it's easier), we have `LEN($G$1:$G$7)>0` - basically "don't look at blank cells".

The other test (`FIND($G$1:$G$7,$A2)=1`) will search for the Prefix in the Con No, and return where it is found (or a `#VALUE!` error if it **isn't**).  We then check "is this at position 1" - in other words, "Is this at the start of the Con No, rather than in the middle".  We don't want to say Con No `CNQ6060` is part of Company AA instead of Company BB by mistake!

So, if the Prefix is at the Start of the Con No, AND it isn't Blank (because there is an infinite amount of Nothing Before, After, and Between every number and letter), then we get it added to our list of Rows.  We then take the smallest row (i.e. closest to the top - change `AGGREGATE(15` to `AGGREGATE(14` if you want the closest to the bottom!), and use that to get the Company Name

Comment: Excellent. I wanted to have a default prefix in the form of an empty string (length=0), so I just removed the `--(LEN($G$1:$G$7)>0)`. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below formal:

`=VLOOKUP(IF(LEFT(A3,1)="6",LEFT(A3,4),IF(LEFT(A3,1)="C",LEFT(A3,2),IF(LEFT(A3,1)="E",LEFT(A3,7)))),$G$3:$H$7,2,0)`

Have in mind that you have to use `'` before the cell value of column A & G in order to convert cell value into text get the correct out comes using `VLOOKUP`

**Result:**

[image]